# garbage integer when adding 2 integer pointer array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I just started learning how to use pointer array and i'm trying out examples to know more about them but i get confused with them easily. So, I tried to do a simple arithmetic calculation using a pointer array.

The user will input 2 string variables for addition. I then reverse the string variable.

```
string reverseString(string s1)
{
   int i = 0;
   int j;

   char temp;

   j = s1.length() - 1;
   while (i < j)
   {
       temp = s1[i];
       s1[i] = s1[j];
       s1[j] = temp;

       i++;
       j--;
   }  

   return s1;   

}
```

I tried to convert 2 string variables i have into a integer pointer array before adding them together

```
void stringtoInt(string& s1, string& s2)
{
   int size1 = s1.size();
   int size2 = s2.size();

   intPtr intArray;
   intPtr intArray2;

   intArray = new int[size1];
   intArray2 = new int[size2];


   for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++)
   {
       intArray[i] = s1[i] - '0';
   }


   for (int i = 0; i < size2; i++)
   {
       intArray2[i] = s1[i] - '0';
   }

   addInteger(intArray, intArray2);

}
```

I passed in 2 integer array in a function and tried to carry some addition calculation

```
void addInteger(intPtr intArray, intPtr intArray2)
{
   int *p = intArray;
   int *q = intArray2;

   intPtr total = new int[MAX];

   int i = 0;

   int sum = 0;
   int carried = 0;

   while (*p != '\0' || *q != '\0')
   {
       *(total + i) = *p + *q + carried;

       if(*(total + i) > 9)
       {
           *(total + i) %= 10;
           carried = 1;
       }

       else 
        carried = 0;    

       i++;
       p++;
       q++;         
   }     

   printArray(total, i);
}
```

And this is how i read my pointer array

```
void printArray(intPtr total, int size)
{    
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << *(total + i);

}
```

After trying to debug this pointer integer array, i still can't figure out what is wrong with them and i just started learning how to use pointer integer array.

Comment: `j = s1.length()` is wherre the problem is...

Comment: There are many problems. Most would probably be solved if you started to use standard C++ containers like `std::vector` and used iterators instead.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I've heard about vectors but I was told to use pointer array to solve this kind of problem instead.

Comment: @barakmanos I had to use that in order to find out the length of my string before swapping the integers around.

Comment: Pointers are a *great* way to get into problems. While a vector isn't protected against going out of bounds (unless you use the `at` member function) they do make it easy to dynamically add and remove elements, and to iterate over elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is how you use the string terminator from the strings and put them into the integer arrays.

The string terminator is `'\0'`, which is equal to zero. That means when you do `'\0' - '0'` the result is (with [ASCII encoding](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii)) `0 - 48`. Not a value you would expect I guess.

That means in your `addInteger` function where you check for the `'\0'` *characters* in your *integer* array you might go out of bounds. That leads to *undefined behavior*.

Or if there is an actual zero in any of the integer arrays you will stop short.

Either way you will get the wrong result.

You can't use the string terminator as a terminator for the integer arrays. You need to either use the actual sizes from the strings and check that. Or, like I mentioned in a comment, use a proper C++ container and iterators (or indexes).

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
j = s1.length();
```

with:

```
j = s1.length()-1;
```

The last character of the string is at `length-1`, not `length`.

Also, in `stringtoInt`, you don't copy the terminating '\0' to `intArray1` and `intArray2`, so this condition:

```
while (*p != '\0' || *q != '\0')
```

is wrong in `addInteger`. Pass the size from `stringtoInt` to `addInteger` and replace the `while` loop with a `for` loop on that size.